# How do I convert ICNS to PNG while removing the extra transparent area?

Tags: macos, icons, png, image-conversion

I have about 200+ .icns files that I would like to convert to png to use somewhere else.

However, the .icns files are a 1024x1024 area that come with a sizeable transparent area around the actual icon. When opened in Preview, I can see that the approximate size of the actual icon is 826x826.

[image: ICNS Icon vs. Actual Size]

If I convert one of these .icns files to png and use it as-is, the icon appears smaller next to the others due to this extra transparent area:

[image]

Is there a way to easily get the actual icon out of all these .icns files? Worst-case scenario, I can manually crop each one in Photoshop, but that can be tedious (and not 100% exact) so I'm hoping there’s a better/automated way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(A) Use the Internal Utility "sips" , which means "Scriptable Image Processing System" ....
That may or may not be enough for your case.

(B) Use [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx) , which will work **Perfectly** for your case.
The main Parameters to consider are:
Either (1) [CROP](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#crop) : get the central region of interest
Or (2) [SHAVE](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#shave) : remove the border
With this, you can Process all your ICNS Icons with a **Single** Command !

Comment: Also try the excellent (trialware?) utility Graphic Converter if you’d rather have a visual way of defining the rules for crop & convert.

Answer (score 0):

(A)
This is my solution using automator:

```
for theFilePath in "$@"; do
sips --cropOffset 1 1 -c 925 925 -o "${theFilePath%%.*}.png" "$theFilePath"
sips -r 180 -o "${theFilePath%%.*}.png" "$theFilePath"
sips --cropOffset 1 1 -c 826 826 -o "${theFilePath%%.*}.png" "$theFilePath"
sips -r 180 -o "${theFilePath%%.*}.png" "$theFilePath"
done
```